# How to stack 4 video JS Players exactly on top of each other in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, video.js

I need a way to stack 4 VideoJS video players exactly on top of each other in React JS. I need to switch between the players on selecting a button.(Button 1,2,3,4 for Players 1,2,3,4 respectively). When switching between the videos the video shouldn't restart and must continue playing in the background. For some reason whatever I do the video player keeps restarting.

Code for the player panel

```
import React from 'react';
import VideoPlayer from './VideoJS/VideoPlayer';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Player.css'
import { useState} from 'react';



const VideoPage = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const fileLocations = location.state.fileLocations;
  const [playerId, setPlayerId] = useState(1);

  const switchCam = (camId) => {
    setPlayerId(camId);
  };

  const videoJsOptions1 = {
    autoplay: true,
    controls: true,
    responsive: true,
    fluid: true,
    sources: [{
      src: fileLocations[0],
      type: 'video/mp4'
    }],
    aspectRatio: '16:9',
  };
  const videoJsOptions2 = {
    autoplay: true,
    muted: true,
    controls: true,
    responsive: true,
    fluid: true,
    sources: [{
      src: fileLocations[1],
      type: 'video/mp4'
    }],
    aspectRatio: '16:9',
  };
  const videoJsOptions3 = {
    autoplay: true,
    muted: true,
    controls: true,
    responsive: true,
    fluid: true,
    sources: [{
      src: fileLocations[2],
      type: 'video/mp4'
    }],
    aspectRatio: '16:9',
  };
  const videoJsOptions4 = {
    autoplay: true,
    muted: true,
    controls: true,
    responsive: true,
    fluid: true,
    sources: [{
      src: fileLocations[3],
      type: 'video/mp4'
    }],
    aspectRatio: '16:9',
  };

  return (
    <div className="grid-container">
      <div className="player">
        <div className="video-wrapper">
          <div className="video-player" style={{ opacity: playerId === 1 ? 1 : 0 }}>
            <VideoPlayer options={videoJsOptions1} />
          </div>
          <div className="video-player" style={{ opacity: playerId === 2 ? 1 : 0 }}>
            <VideoPlayer options={videoJsOptions2} />
          </div>
          <div className="video-player" style={{ opacity: playerId === 3 ? 1 : 0 }}>
            <VideoPlayer options={videoJsOptions3} />
          </div>
          <div className="video-player" style={{ opacity: playerId === 4 ? 1 : 0 }}>
            <VideoPlayer options={videoJsOptions4} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='view-selection'>
        <div className='camera'><button className='camera-button' onClick={() => switchCam(1)}>Camera 1</button></div>
        <div className='camera'><button className='camera-button' onClick={() => switchCam(2)}>Camera 2</button></div>
        <div className='camera'><button className='camera-button' onClick={() => switchCam(3)}>Camera 3</button></div>
        <div className='camera'><button className='camera-button' onClick={() => switchCam(4)}>Camera 4</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoPage;
```

Code For the VideoPlayer

```
import React from 'react';
import videojs from 'video.js';
import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css';

export const VideoPlayer = (props) => {
  const videoRef = React.useRef(null);
  const playerRef = React.useRef(null);
  const {options, onReady} = props;

  React.useEffect(() => {

    // Make sure Video.js player is only initialized once
    if (!playerRef.current) {
      // The Video.js player needs to be _inside_ the component el for React 18 Strict Mode. 
      const videoElement = document.createElement("video-js");

      videoElement.classList.add('vjs-big-play-centered');
      videoRef.current.appendChild(videoElement);

      const player = playerRef.current = videojs(videoElement, options, () => {
        videojs.log('player is ready');
        onReady && onReady(player);
      });

    // You could update an existing player in the `else` block here
    // on prop change, for example:
    } else {
        const player = playerRef.current;

        player.autoplay(options.autoplay);
        player.src(options.sources);
        player.muted(options.muted);
        player.load();
    }
  }, [options, videoRef]);

  // Dispose the Video.js player when the functional component unmounts
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const player = playerRef.current;

    return () => {
      if (player && !player.isDisposed()) {
        player.dispose();
        playerRef.current = null;
      }
    };
  }, [playerRef]);

  return (
    <div data-vjs-player>
      <div ref={videoRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default VideoPlayer;
```

Thanking in advance.